# Filter a SQL replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

I'm trying to replicate a SQL database but I want to apply a filter based on date.
The database has more than 6000 tables and all of them have a datetime column (stamp) with the same name "usrdate".
Is it possible to apply a filter to be applied to all columns?
The goal is to have multiple databases in the replication site with data between periods.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean Microsoft SQL Server, yes you can apply a [**Filter on the Publication**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/filter-published-data?view=sql-server-ver15) using that `usrdate` column on each Article you're replicating, but you'll need to add the Filter for each replicated article. Also there are some limitations (mentioned in the previously linked docs) and using **Publication Filters** aren't applied like regular SQL predicates so they may be less performant than doing it in SQL yourself.

You may be best off creating a series of Views on top of the Tables you want to replicate that apply the date filter as a predicate in SQL, which you probably can more easily script out than trying to add the **Publication Filter** to each Article.